# Integrar Facebook Login na aplicação. Erro no keytool

Tags: android

Olá,

Estou tentando realizar integrar o login do Facebook na minha aplicação, para quando o usuário se cadastrar ele poder fazer isso com o Facebook.
Já vi vários tutoriais aqui - no site-  e pela internet de como se faz. Mas para pegar a chave hash estou com um problema.

O que estou fazendo:

- Entro no CMD
- Faço o comando para ir até o diretório cd C:/usuario/artur/.android
- Depois aqui dentro eu coloco os comandos que o próprio site do facebook ensina e outros tutoriais também:
- *keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore
  %HOMEPATH%.android\debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl
  base64*

Mas aparece a mensagem mostrando que o windows não reconhece o comando **keytool**

Em outros tutoriais que vi, ao invés de apontar o caminho para **user/artur/.android** era para apontar no cmd para **c:/programs/java/java7**

Tentei fazer isto e aqui dentro reconhece o comando **keytool**, mas não reconhece o comando **openssl**.

Sério, devo ter visto no minimo umas 10 tutoriais diferente, desde quando a IDE principal era o Eclipse até tutoriais mais recentes com android 2.3
Alguém já passou por isso ? Se alguém puder me dar uma luz, porque já não sei mais o que faço ou o que estou fazendo de errado

Comment: Talvez você precise instalar o OpenSSL e configura-lo como variável de ambiente no Windows. Você consegue encontrar alguns tutoriais sobre isso no Google. Aproveite também para configurar o `keytool` na variável de ambiente `Path` para que você possa acessa-lo sem ter que ir no diretório `c:/programs/java/java7`